# Is there a way to make Discord.js role that removes from user by it's self after ( some ) time?

Tags: javascript, discord

Is there a way to make Discord.js role that removes from a user by its self after ( some ) time?

I have this Idea for buying roles for $ or for server points.
Maybe you guys have a similar source code or something, It would help a lot!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I think you would have to architect your application to handle removing them. For example, when the user pays for the membership you could store their username (or unique user ID), the date they paid, how long their membership is for. Then you could run a program everyday to check for people who need to be removed and do the proper removal. You could even further enhance it by adding additional features like automatically messaging the user X days prior to their membership expiring, etc.